# real analysis - 2 very challenging proofs (multivariable real functions)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus, contest-math

Struggle for the long time with 2 proofs from real analysis(multivariable real functions):

- 1.)Let $\Delta$ be defined as follows: $\Delta u := \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \delta^2_{x_i, x_i} $,  $u \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{R^n}$ be open and bounded. Assume that $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega}) $ and that   $\Delta u \geq 0 $.
  Prove that:

  - $ sup${ $u$: $u\in \Omega$ }$ $ =  $ sup${ $u$: $u\in \delta \Omega$ }$ $   ($\delta \Omega$ denotes the boundary of set $\Omega$)
- 2.)Prove that there exists at most 1 function $u \in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\bar{\Omega})$ that satisfies simultaneously 2 conditions:
- a) $\forall x\in \Omega: \Delta u(x) = f(x)$
- b) $\forall x \in \delta \Omega: u(x) = g(x)$

  I have already spent 8 days to derive proofs for the above problems, but I am completely stuck! I would be extremely thankful for help. I would very appreciate someone's help!!!

Comment: Dear users of this profile. I really beg you on providing me help since I am very desperate in finding solution to these propositions. I would be very, very, very thankful for your help.

Comment: For $(1)$, look into subharmonic functions and the maximum principle. Use the maximum principle to prove the uniqueness in $(2)$.

Comment: $Fimpellizieri, I see your hint. However, is there the possibility of doing these proofs without the use of machinery?

Comment: What exactly do you mean without the use of machinery? My hints were aimed at general, theoretical proofs.

Comment: $Fimpellizieri, I mean whether it is possible to derive proofs for these problems only by the use of fundamentals of multivariable real functions?

Comment: $Fimpellizieri, would you be able to post general strategy of proofs for these problems or to provide outline of proofs?

Comment: It is always possible to prove everything from fundamentals.  It's just foolish to do so since doing so fails to provide insight to the proof writer or to the reader.

Comment: @Eric Towers, would you be able to provide outline for these problems?

Comment: The proof for $(1)$ is not particularly simple but it is well documented (look into the topics I mentioned!). Now, if you assume $(1)$, question $(2)$ is relatively simple. A hint for it: let $u, v$ be solutions. What can you say of $u-v$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri, found proof for (1) in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489107/maximum-principle-for-subharmonic-functions

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about the mean value property for (sub)harmonic functions? This is used for proving the result you want. $$-\triangle u = (\leq) 0 \quad  \Longrightarrow \quad u(x) = (\leq) \frac{1}{B(x,r)}\int_{B(x,r)} u(y) dy \quad \forall B(x,r)\subset U.$$ The proof only uses calculus, but I would say the trick in this calculation is not worth the times trying to figure out by yourself. And you see from above, if $u$ attains a strict max inside $U$ say a $x_0$, we will not have 
$$u(x_0) \leq \frac{1}{B(x_0,r)}\int_{B(x_0,r)} u(y) dy\quad \text{ for some } r \text{ such that } B(x_0,r)\subset U.$$