# Let $v$ sub-harmonic s.t. $v$ has his maximum in $\Omega $. Then $v$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n $ a bounded open domain and $v:\Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ sub-harmonic i.e. $\Delta v\geq 0$. Show that if $v$ has his maximum in the interior of $\Omega $, then $v$ is constant in $\Omega $.

**Proof**

Let $x_0\in \Omega $ s.t. $v(x_0)\geq v(x)$ for all $x\in \Omega $. I'm trying to show that $v(x)=v(x_0)$ for all $x\in \Omega $. I know that $\Delta v(x_0)=0$ and $\nabla v(x_0)=0$ but I cant conclude. I also know that $v(x)\leq \frac{1}{|B(x_0,r)|}\int_{B(x_0,r)}u(t)dt$ for all $B(x_0,r)\subset \subset \Omega $, but I can't conclude.

Comment: Are you assuming that $v$ is continuous and do you know the corresponding result for harmonic functions? If yes then your question has already been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489107/maximum-principle-for-subharmonic-functions?rq=1

Comment: @Thomas : Yes (since $\Delta u$ is well defined ;-)). Thanks for the link :-)